# how to make multiple notification base on date and time saved saved in sqlite database in android

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-alarms

can anyone show me how to set multiple notification in android?
well you see im quite new to android dev so i was wondering how to make a notification base on saved time and date in my sqlite database.

the scenario is that when a user finishes filling up a form that has for example event name, event date and event time fields and when he saves it a toast will appear indicating that the event has been saved.
now when the data is stored in the database the notification will appear in the given event date and event time set by the user and the notification message will be the event name.

so can anyone please show me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go -

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
            notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
            notificationIntent.putExtra("eventName", eventName);
            notificationIntent.putExtra("description", description);

            PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), notifNumber, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Notifnumber is a random number generated every time.

Comment: so how can i set this notification base on my saved time and date in sqlite database?

Comment: So after the pending intent you need to initialize an alarm manager and set and alarm. Then you need to create an AlarmReceiver which handles the alarm. Kindly follow this - http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html

Comment: @Ambuj Kathotiya  What does the "...addCategory("...DEFAULT")" do in your above answer?

Comment: @AJW [From Google Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters)

"A string containing additional information about the kind of component that should handle the intent. Any number of category descriptions can be placed in an intent, but most intents do not require a category."


Also this - "Activities will very often need to support the CATEGORY_DEFAULT so that they can be found by Context.startActivity()"